# Validação para verificar se o registro está sendo usado antes de deletar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

O MVC do meu projeto está estuturado em serviços, controllers, Views e models.

Minha tela de deleção funciona, porém quando o registro é utilizado em outras tabelas exibe esse erro.

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_XYZ". The conflict occurred in database "ETEST", table "dbo.TEST", column 'ID_TEST'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Isso acontece porque a PK da tabela é FK em outras tabelas.

Eu gostaria que antes de deletar, o sistema fizesse uma verificação se o registro é usado na banco.
Para mostrar uma mensagem para o usuário amigavél antes de tentar deletar.
Ex.: Registro não pode ser excluído por estar em uso.

Como construo essa validação?

**Model**

```
public int Id {get; set;}

[Display(Name = "Codigo", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.TestResources))]
[Required]
public string Codigo { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Descricao", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.TestResources))]
[Required]
public string Descricao { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "UsuarioAnalistaCusto", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.TestResources))]
[Required]
public string UsuarioAnalistaCusto { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
public void Excluir(int id)
    {
        this.Service.Delete(id);
    }
```

**Services**

```
public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var item = this.context.Test.Find(id);
            this.context.Test.Remove(item);
            base.Save();
        }
```

**Context**

```
namespace TXT.Test.eTest.DataAccess
{
    public partial class EContext : DbContext
    {
        static EContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ECContext>(null);
        }

        public EContext(bool proxyCreationEnabled = true)
            : base("Name=EContext")
        {
            base.Database.CommandTimeout = 60 * 5; // TOOO: utilizar configuration
            base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;

            base.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Desenho> Desenhos { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EMPRESAMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FORNECEDORMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DESENHOMap());
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Se não usa EF, você tem que usar o padrão do seu repositório. Como é este acesso ao banco?

Comment: o Banco está mapeado, dentro de uma classe que chama DataAccess

Comment: Mas usa contexto. Esse DataAccess simula um contexto? Como é isso?

Comment: Postei um exemplo de como é feito pra vc ver

Comment: Então. Usa o Entity Framework Sim. O contexto deriva de `DbContext`. Neste caso é só conferir se a propriedade de navegação pai não é nula, mas ainda considerando que você desabilita o proxy dinâmico, isto pode ficar mais complicado. Precisa de uma resposta?

Comment: hm.. compreendo. Seria mais fácil fazer um tratamento de erros para o usuário, ao invés da validação?.R= Esse registro não pode ser apagado pois está sendo utilizado.

Comment: Pode ser. Vou sugerir algo.

Comment: Não é necessário colocar as tecnologias no título - é para isso que servem as tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu sistema na verdade usa Entity Framework sim. A maneira correta de avisar o usuário que o registro não pode ser excluído é algo do tipo:

```
var registro = context.Registros.Include(r => r.RegistroDependente).FirstOfDefault(/* Coloque aqui a condição para selecionar */);
if (registro.RegistroDependente != null) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Este registro não pode ser apagado pelo motivo tal.");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Mto Bom.. consegui! Obrigada

Comment: Cigano, interresante, se a gente remover o Include, ou seja deixássemos o Lazyload trabalhar um pouquinho, isto iria mudar muito o desempenho?

Comment: Em todo caso me lembrei daquela nossa conversa sobre desativar o AutoDetectChanges.

Comment: Ia porque sem `Include` o registro dependente ia receber um Proxy Dinâmico, que sempre é mais lento que o `join` em si.

Answer (score 1):

Retirado de: [SQL Server: how to know if any row is referencing the row to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6301968/1387277)

Se o seu sistema for multi usuário, o que provavelmente é, *verificar* se o registro pode ser deletado pode causar um problema de corrida crítica:

Imagine que o sistema determina que o registro pode ser excluído, e permite que o usuário o faça (ou mesmo prossiga imediatamente para excluir).

Imagine que entre as duas operações um outro usuário cria um registro relacionado (muito menos provável se não passarem pelo usuário entre confirmar que pode ser deletado e o ato de deletar, mas ainda assim não impossível): ocorre exatamente o erro que você tentou evitar, e que, por verificar antes, você considera que não poderia ocorrer, e, portanto, provavelmente não trata.

---

Assim, a solução adequada é mais simples que o que você perguntou: tente fazer a operação, e trate o erro. Se o erro de chave externa for lançado, trate-o e devolva uma mensagem para o usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Extamente, concordo com RSinohara, seria muito mais colocar um try/catch dentro do delete do serviço, no exemplo abaixo funciona no SQL Server:

```
public void Delete(int id)
{
      try
      {
         var item = this.context.Test.Find(id);
         this.context.Test.Remove(item);
         base.Save();
      }
      catch (DbUpdateException ex)
      {
         var sqlException = ex.GetBaseException() as SqlException;

         if (sqlException != null)
         {
             var numero = sqlException.Number;

             if (numero == 547)
             {
               throw ex.Message = "Existe outras entidade relacionadas a essa, não foi possível apagar.";
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Controller vc poderia usar outro try/catch para obter a mensagem da exceção lançanda da camada de baixo e colocar no ModelState.AddModelError como o Cigano fez.

Comment: Não precisa `try` / `catch` porque o ASP.NET contém o evento `OnException` no *Controller* que intercepta qualquer tipo de exceção com mais propriedade. Fica mais fácil de produzir telas de erro, logs, etc.

Comment: Isso se você estiver usando ASP.NET, normalmente a camada de Acesso a dados e Serviço não sabem que o ASP.NET existe. As exceções são estouradas nas camadas de baixo.

Comment: Camada de dados? Serviços? Do que está falando? A pergunta é sobre ASP.NET MVC. Essas camadas não existem no MVC.

Comment: Concordo, só respondi de forma mais abrangente. ;)